# How to get height of div using jquery in IE

Tags: jquery

I have a div, i want get height of the div.

```
$('.graph_container').css('height')
```

and css is

```
.graph_container {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin-top:1em;
    position:relative;
}
```

since height is not mentioned, in IE it give 'auto'. How can i get exacte height.

I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.graph_container').height()
```

which returns a number.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate height of any element or window or document we can make use of the "height()" method of jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("p").append($("p").height()+" px");
$("div.divContainer").append($("div.divContainer").height()+" px");
$("div.document").append($(document).height()+" px");
$("div.window").append($(window).height()+" px");         
});

<div class="document">Height of this document is: </div>
<div class="window">Height of this window is: </div>
<div class="divContainer">Height of this div container is: </div> 
<p>Height of this paragraph is: </p>
```